# what is causing apache2 not to install in termux?

Tags: node.js, npm, apache2, bootstrap-5, termux

I

I am watching a freecodecamp video on bootstrap and sass. I have to use termux to run the npm(I am new to to npm) but I couldn't access all the packages I created with any android editor. Then I needed how to run the html. I searched and found out I need to install apache2. After many attempt it keep on failing to install.

Comment: Please provide details on the environment, how you are installing Apache, and the errors. Without details, we can only guess.

Comment: the environment is termux. I am using the command 'pkg install apache2'